# Wasn't simply a case of negligence

Tags: meaning, adverbs, ambiguity

> a. The management says that the fire started because a technician was
> negligent. But it wasn't **only** a case of a technician being
> negligent. The whole system was flawed.
>
> b. The management says that the fire started because a technician was
> negligent. But it wasn't **just** a case of a technician being
> negligent. The whole system was flawed.
>
> c. The management says that the fire started because a technician was
> negligent. But it wasn't **simply** a case of a technician being
> negligent. The whole system was flawed.

I think in (a) and (b) a technician was indeed negligent, but the fire did not start merely because of that, and more important and structural factors were involved.

But it seems to me that (c) is ambiguous. I think it could mean the same as the other two, but there is also the possibility that no technician was negligent at all.

Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think it makes a blind bit of difference whether you use ***only, just,*** or ***simply*** (or indeed, ***soley*** or ***merely***, among others). The meaning is the same in all cases (there was both a negligent technician ***and*** a flawed system). It's just / only / simply a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 4):

I think even C means that there was a negligent technician. It **wasn't simply** that, there was more involved.

If it said "It **wasn't** a case of a technician being negligent...", then that would be discounting management's explanation entirely.